# Eclipse showing old output in console

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I have a very strange issue. I have an application that im building in eclipse.

I have a line which is commented out.

```
//System.out.println("starting new thread with conf: " + Main.config("instruments"));
```

I hit the run button yet i still see this output in the console. I add some more output.

```
System.out.println("What the hell");
//System.out.println("starting new thread with conf: " + Main.config("instruments"));
```

Yet in the console i still see this (below) without the new output iv added

```
starting new thread with conf: EUR_USD%2CGBP_USD
```

It may be worth noting that this (folder) workspace is shared with a virtual machine.

Does eclipse have some sort of cache that is causing this to happen?

Comment: I've encountered strange behaviour of Eclipse's console before. Run your program from the command line and check if it's OK.

Comment: I exported the project as a jar and ran the jar command line. its still doing the same thing. I also just commented out all of the code in my Main.class yet the programme still runs... its as if eclipse is stuck on a previous save.

Comment: try to clean and build project

Answer (score 0):

There was an external Jar file missing. For some reason this caused none of the updated code to be output to console.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just right click on console window and **Terminate /Disconnect all**.
2. Run the class again
3. Done !!!

Answer (score 0):

It is either because ***you have chosen to run the previous program after every built*** or ***your current changes are not saved before running***

lets solve both problems:
case1: Windows->preferences->Run/Debug->Launnching (DOUBLE CLICK)->Launch Operation (CHOOSE "LAUNCH THE SELECTED RESOURCE..." & ALSO CHOOSE "LAUNCH THE ASSOCIATED PROJECT")

case2: Windows->preferences->Run/Debug->Launnching (DOUBLE CLICK)->Save Required dirty...->ALWAYS

restart the eclipse...solved!!!